# How do I make each image have the corresponding tag?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, data-augmentation, imagedatagenerator

with the following code, I augmented some images and I would like to know how I can make each generated image have the corresponding label 
I try with save_prefix = +label but it just prints the same name for all images 
I appreciate any help or comment

````
def get_augmt(image,model):
    i = 0
    img_list =[]
    for batch in model.flow (x= image,
                            batch_size = 1,
                            save_to_dir ='probando', 
                            save_prefix =" " + label,
                            save_format ='jpeg',
                            subset = None):
        i += 1
        img_list.append(batch)
        if i > 5:
            return img_list  ```


pr["img_aug"] = pr["images"].apply(lambda x: get_augmt(x,datagen))
````

Answer (score 0):

It prints the same name for all images 'couse you're taking the `label` variable as global and never change it in the function.

If in pr["image"] you are able to attach to each image a label it will be easier to access it from the function `get_augmt`.

Otherways you can use `i` instead and the code would be:

````
def get_augmt(image,model):
    i = 0
    img_list =[]
    for batch in model.flow (x= image,
                            batch_size = 1,
                            save_to_dir ='probando', 
                            save_prefix =" " + str(i),
                            save_format ='jpeg',
                            subset = None):
        i += 1
        img_list.append(batch)
        if i > 5:
            return img_list  ```


pr["img_aug"] = pr["images"].apply(lambda x: get_augmt(x,datagen))
````